# Publish report that uses SSAS cube to app.powerbi.com?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I've been searching for an answer, but haven't found anything concrete. The most recent replies to this specific question are over five years old.

I created an SSAS cube with VS SSDT and I was able to create a chart using Power Bi Desktop. So far so good. I then saved the file in my Desktop.

Now I'm trying to publish this report to app.powerbi.com so that other users (also with a Pro license) can view the chart through their browser.

With my Power BI Pro license, at $9.99/month, can I publish the report and the cube to app.powerbi.com?

If not, what's needed so that I can view, in a browser, the same chart I created in Power Bi Desktop?

Comment: You should be able to publish and view in the browser in this case so long as you can get the connection to the SSAS cube set up in the Power BI Service (this might require a data gateway if the cube isn't in the cloud).

Comment: Two questions: 1) Can an SSAS cube be published to app.powerbi.com? 2) Where can I find information on creating a data gateway that will connect the report (in app.powerbi.com) to my local SSAS cube? Thanks.

Comment: I think we're a bit off-topic for StackOverflow. Maybe try posting on the forums here (they're quite active): https://community.powerbi.com/